# Python turtle not moving on arrow press

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make my turtle (main_ship) move across the bottom of my screen according to when the user presses the left and right arrow keys but the turtle is not moving. I have used the same code before when making Pong so I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Game")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

main_ship = turtle.Turtle()
main_ship.speed(0)
main_ship.shape("turtle")
main_ship.color("green")
main_ship.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=4)
main_ship.penup()
main_ship.goto(0, -290)
main_ship.left(90)

def main_ship_right():
    x = main_ship.xcor()
    x += 20
    main_ship.setx(x)
def main_ship_left():
    x = main_ship.xcor()
    x -= 20
    main_ship.setx(x)

while True:
    wn.update()
    wn.mainloop()

    wn.listen()
    wn.onkeypress(main_ship_right, "Right")
    wn.onkeypress(main_ship_left, "Left")
```

When I press the arrow keys, nothing happens but the code still runs and there are no error messages.

Comment: you have to assign keys before mainloop(). And you don't need `while True` because `mainloop()` runs all time till you close window.

Comment: and remove `wn.tracer(0)` or you will have to use `wm.update()` in every function which change turtle position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign keys before `mainloop()` which runs all time till you close window.

You don't need `while True` because `mainloop()` already runs internal loop.

You may have to remove `wm.tracer(0)` or you will have to run `wn.update()` to refresh elements in window.

```
import turtle

# --- functions ---

def main_ship_right():
    x = main_ship.xcor()
    x += 20
    main_ship.setx(x)
    wn.update()

def main_ship_left():
    x = main_ship.xcor()
    x -= 20
    main_ship.setx(x)
    wn.update()

# --- main ---

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Game")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

main_ship = turtle.Turtle()
main_ship.speed(0)
main_ship.shape("turtle")
main_ship.color("green")
main_ship.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=4)
main_ship.penup()
main_ship.goto(0, -290)
main_ship.left(90)
wn.update()

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(main_ship_right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(main_ship_left, "Left")

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For this style of motion, there's another way to implement it.  The idea is to leave the cursor moving in it's original orientation, but use `settiltangle()` to make it look like it's facing upward.

This lets us use `forward(20)` and `backward(20)` to move our cursor, and not have to write:

```
x = main_ship.xcor()
x += 20
main_ship.setx(x)
```

Works great for Space Invader style games, where the player faces upwards but moves sideways:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Game")
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)

main_ship = Turtle('turtle')
main_ship.speed('fastest')
main_ship.color('green')
main_ship.shapesize(stretch_wid=2, stretch_len=4)
main_ship.settiltangle(90)
main_ship.penup()
main_ship.sety(-290)

screen.onkeypress(partial(main_ship.forward, 20), 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(partial(main_ship.backward, 20), 'Left')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Only works in the turtle library that comes with Python -- online Python development sites usually provide limited turtle implementations that don't include methods like `settiltangle()`.